# Isolated vs. Non-Isolated AC Mains to 5v Converter

Tags: ac, esp8266, ac-dc

I am working on an internet connected lamp project that includes an AC dimmer and touch sensor. I am wanting to design a custom PCB but am confused if I should use an isolated or non-isolated regulator for the ESP8266.

Isolated regulators seem to be more expensive and not fit the small form factor required, but I understand it could be a safety issue. The only user-touchable part of it would be a metal surface which is connected over a single wire to a touch sensor.

The non-isolated one I'm looking at is this one here. [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mornsun-america,-llc/LS01-K3B05SS/13530983?utm_adgroup=General&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax:%20Smart%20Shopping_Product_Zombie%20SKUS&utm_term=&utm_content=General&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkMGcBhCSARIsAIW6d0Dp4_VRoJ2WovS87zhgn_OJqxslyMIOKkc73hBdQpIHLZ0sIThrzasaAvL2EALw_wcB)

Also, if non-isolated is okay, do they make converters like these for 3.3v? I can't find anything like that, so I was planning on just using an LDO for the ESP8266.

Comment: If the touch sensor is powered by non-isolated supply, and the touch sensor is connected to the lamp metal case which people can touch, what do you think happens if people touch the lamp metal?

Comment: Yikes! The datasheet has a warning "Warning: Non-isolated power supply, there is no insulation protection between output and input dangerous voltage, beware of electric shock!" DON'T USE THIS AC/DC CONVERTER IN YOUR APPLICATION!!!!!

Comment: Do you understand why people are using isolated power supplies?

Answer (score 5):

### AC mains requires isolation

You seem to be confused either about what AC mains power is, or the manner in which it is dangerous to humans.  The Web can set you straight on that point, which I won't belabor.

So you use a non-isolated supply. That means the metal parts you spoke of will be in direct contact with one of the two *supply conductors* on the AC mains supply.

Now some people say "Well, one of those supply conductors is NEUTRAL, AND THEREFORE SAFE".  First, on most electrical outlets, lamps use a plug type which is reversible - you only have a 50/50 chance of it being the *live* conductor and knocking the user into next Tuesday (or the pearly gates) when they touch it.

Second, outlets are often miswired - there's no way to know, because this doesn't affect anything if appliances are built properly (UL, TUV, etc.)  But third, a simple wire break on the neutral wire in between your lamp and the supply, will energize the neutral at line voltage (since it's being connected to line via the loads on the far side of the break).  This will happen due to the load of your very own appliance.  [John Ward describes this on a whole-house basis here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE), but with 2-wire cords you are effectively using neutral as PEN.*

### Grounding keeps you honest

If you must build an AC lamp, use a 3-wire cord and physically ground the lamp chassis to ground.  **This is a best practice anytime you are home-building any equipment.**  However it is not a panacea since people often stick grounded sockets on non-grounded circuits, meaning ground isn't really there. And ground can also fail silently, since failure of a ground won't prevent any equipment from working.

However, grounding the fixture would *preclude* use of a non-isolated power supply, since it would immediately short to ground and either make magic smoke or trip the circuit breaker.  Even a neutral-ground short will trip a GFCI/RCD.

### But low voltage makes lamp design easy

None of the above is our problem if we use a *UL/BSI-Listed* "Wall Wart" power supply to deliver low voltage to the lamp.   Listed wall-warts are commodities even amongst cheap Chinese; because 99% of use of wall-wart power supplies is by vendors who aspire to be placed on retail store shelves in the wealthy West, where *listing* is a requirement.

By removing AC mains altogether from the lamp, we also remove AC mains *hazard* altogether from the lamp. Every type of light emitter is readily available in low voltage (except maybe HID but I don't think you want that), so this isn't really a burden to the lamp designer.  Much the opposite - it's a *liberation*.

---

* North America once used PEN for dryers and ranges, but had such a string of fatalities that they outlawed it in 1996.  It still racks up a death toll because NFPA doesn't have the authority to compel retrofits.  Worse, the news calls it "mis-wiring" when *the wiring was correct*, it just had an ordinary wire failure. Wires fail and that shouldn't kill people.

Comment: Can you explain the "PEN" reference? I think it refers to the use of three prong connectors for 220 VAC and neutral without a fourth safety (earth) connection, and perhaps it is an abbreviation for Power Earth Neutral. But I could not find a reference other than sites like https://homeapricot.com/do-dryers-come-with-power-cords-quick-answers/

Comment: @PStechPaul Protective Earth Neutral https://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-matters/years/2021/84-march-2021/broken-pen/#:~:text=A%20protective%20earthed%20neutral%20(PEN,PME%20supply%20service%20earthing%20system.

Comment: @PStechPaul Well it's a British term for that thing, but yes, you have the gist.  Here's a video where it's discussed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE  The vid shows it in the context of a whole house, but it's seen in America in the context of 3-prong dryers and ranges (just make the mental note that we have a second hot/live wire and no RCD/GFCI).  Also on subpanels, although that was banned in 2008 for the reasons covered in the vid.

Comment: I think I need to look into the theory of isolated vs. non-isolated converters more. From my past understanding having a DC 5v output is safe no matter how it is created, unless of course the regulator system fails. For example, if you were to hook up an oscilloscope to an isolated vs non-isolated output, would it look the same? If so what is the risk of non-isolated regulators under normal working conditions? This is all just thinking about it, I understand I need to use an isolated regulator in my system.

Comment: @VeraFodor You are *presuming* isolation just happens. If you power a 5V supply off 230V non-isolated, your output wires are actually 230V and 235V. They are 5VDC *relative to each other* but they are also 230-235VAC relative to earth, and that's what will kill you.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree that in most cases, especially for hobbyists, it is best to recommend full isolation, and firmly warn against anything other than galvanic (well-insulated) isolation. But the fact is that currents less than about 1 mA are not harmful, and cannot even be sensed by most people.

So, at the risk of being down-voted, I would say that as long as you use sufficiently large and reliable resistors (perhaps two 220k in series) to detect the capacitance of human body touch, it is adequately safe. Even well constructed isolated power supplies will have some interwinding capacitance from primary to secondary that can provide several hundred microamps of leakage, and many such transformers are cheaply made with windings separated by only a layer of insulating tape. Overheating, or manufacturing defects, or environmental deterioration, can cause higher levels of leakage, or even direct contact, which poses a much higher risk than the known quantities afforded by properly chosen resistors.

If the OP can provide a circuit diagram and specs for the design, showing only high resistance connection to the touch sensor, I see no reason to demand the use of an isolated supply. And it should be possible to make a tester using a neon lamp with a 100k parallel resistor, which should take at least 1 mA to GND to light. Or you can use a 1x 1 Meg scope probe to see how much AC voltage is imposed to GND by the proposed sensor. You may find that the isolated supply shows more leakage current than the 400k sensor.

Comment: Power supplies with capacitors to floating ground from phase and neutral give an unpleasant "bite". This would be under 1 mA. That is between the floating ground and a capacitively grounded body on a seat. I suspect your 440k would be safe but potentially unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

if your touch sensor provides the 3000V isolation that is not provided by the power supply then by all means go for it.

If not, look for an isolated supply. LS03-13B03R3 perhaps.

Comment: That isolated supply is perfect!

Comment: it just showed up on digikey's search.